# Remove directory names from url

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, lumen

I have a new Project in Lumen which needs to be deployed to the Staging server and i have done it. I am facing issues with removing the names of directories from the URL. My project Directory is like this:

```
DIR - ProjectName
   DIR - ProjectName {Lumen files inside this directory}
     DIR - app
     DIR - bootstrap
     DIR - database
     DIR - public
     DIR - resources
     DIR - storage
     DIR - tests
     DIR - Vendor
```

so currently to view my application i need to enter a url like this :

`http://stagingserverdomain.com/ProjectName/ProjectName/public/login`

However i would like my url to be like this:

`http://stagingserverdomain.com/ProjectName/login`

I have tried the many answers form SO but it does not work.

Comment: You need to check your server settings for either Nginx or Apache. Change the document root variable and you are good to go. Or just move up all your folders to the parent folder.

Comment: yes i know that, but still the project is deployed in this way and i am not allowed to move the files as parent directory contains some other files ( not related to development )

Comment: Thinking about it, moving up the folder won't even work, because Nginx/Apache is not even looking for the public folder. If you really cannot change these settings, I'd suggest contacting your webmaster and having him do it. If they won't do it either, go with thickguru's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^Projectname/login$ /ProjectName/ProjectName/public/login [L]
```

It should leave you with the following URL:

`http://stagingserverdomain.com/ProjectName/login`

Comment: Well isn't that tackling the issue without solving the underlying problem?

Comment: what will be the location of .htaccess file ?

Comment: Just put it in your root.

Comment: i did that, no change

Comment: Old url is still working and the new one throws NOT FOUND error form apache

Answer (score 0):

Great question!  Add this [Apache `httpd`](http://ports.su/www/apache-httpd) [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) to the appropriate server definition inside your `httpd.conf` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(ProjectName)/((?!\1).*)  /$1/$1/public/$2
```

Alternatively, add this to a `.htaccess` file at the root of your web-server, e.g., where the first `ProjectName` directory is located:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(ProjectName)/((?!\1).*)   $1/$1/public/$2
```

Alternatively, add this to a `.htaccess` file within the first `ProjectName` directory (where the second `ProjectName` directory is located):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^((?!ProjectName).*)    ProjectName/public/$1
```

Alternatively (and this is the recommended course of action), switch to [`nginx`](http://ports.su/www/nginx), and do this:

```
location /ProjectName {
    rewrite ^/([^/]+)/((?!\1).*)$   /$1/$1/public/$2;
}
```

The above code ensures that the [`rewrite`](http://nginx.org/r/rewrite) will only happen if your URLs don't already contain `ProjectName/ProjectName` (using the *lookahead assertions* of [PCRE](http://ports.su/devel/pcre), which is the library both [NGINX](http://ports.su/www/nginx) and [Apache](http://ports.su/www/apache-httpd) use for support of the [regular expressions](http://mdoc.su/n,f,d/pcrepattern.3)), so, there won't be any infinite redirect loops.

Comment: Ok, this worked to some extent, I tried adding the `. htaccess` to the first `ProjectName` Directory as that was most convenient, However the url `http://stagingserverdomain.com/ProjectName/login` still takes me to a 404 page but this time the page is rendered by lumen framework and not by apache Server.

Comment: @AngryCoder, then I'm afraid you'll have to you'll can add a `[R]` at the end of `RewriteRule` to issue HTTP redirects from short to long notation, as your Lumen thing must be looking into the original request URL for final processing, not the internally-rewritten one like most things do in most cases.

Comment: @AngryCoder, have you tried adding `[R]` as I suggested?  If that works for you, and resolves the question, I'd appreciate an upvote and accept for my work.

Comment: yes I have tried that too, but this did not solve the problem

Comment: @AngryCoder, I think you should try it again.  Having an `[R]` will definitely be a good compromise solution, where you could still use short URLs as needed, and they'll simply be mapped to the long ones automatically.